# Delete a range of keys in a binary search tree in better than $O(n\lg n)$?

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees, search-trees

Obviously, the brute force method of:

```
DeleteRange(root, low, high)
    for n = low to high
        if n == root.key // key found
            return DeleteNode(root) // O(lg n) to delete
        elseif n < root.key // in left sub-tree
            root.left = DeleteRange(root.left, n, high) // recur into left sub-tree
        elseif n > root.key // in right sub-tree
            root.right = DeleteRange(root.right, n, high) // recur into right sub-tree
        else // root.key == null, key not found
            return null
   return root
```

would take $O(n\lg n)$ time. So is there any "smarter" way of deletion that would do the same thing with less complexity, perhaps pruning entire sub-trees at once? Assume that the deleted nodes are not needed and the only concern is with returning the root of a binary search tree where the nodes between the range of two keys are deleted.

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint: Try a recursive algorithm.  If `root < low`, what should you do?  Which children of the root do you need to look at?  If `root > high`, what then?  And if `low <= root <= high`, what then?

Comment: Are you familiar with the technique called *threading*? (searchable term)

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in a data structure called [TeardownTree](https://github.com/kirillkh/rs_teardown_tree). It supports `delete_range` operation that works in $O(k + \log n)$ time, where $n$ is the initial number of items in the tree and $k$ is the number of items deleted (and returned to the caller). Full disclosure: I am the author.

I have to emphasize that the data structure does not support the `insert` operation, but is optimized for `clone` and `delete_range`. I have written up an informal [description of the algorithm](https://github.com/kirillkh/rs_teardown_tree/blob/master/delete_range.md). With all the optimizations the code is now significantly different from that document, but it should be enough to grasp the idea.